# "The name xxx does not exist in the current context" after adding LoginView

Tags: asp.net, security, loginview

I have a simple, single-page in ASP.NET (C#). I wanted to add login control, so I just added LoginView as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">

    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
        </asp:Login>
    </AnonymousTemplate>

    <LoggedInTemplate>
        ... here I put all the page elements (buttons, grid views, etc.)
    </LoggedInTemplate>

</asp:LoginView>   

</form>
```

When I run my project I get compilation errors in my code-behing file:

```
The name xxxx does not exist in the current context
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new in ASP.NET, so probably it is some stupid mistake I make.

Comment: What is xxxx?  Is that the name of something?  Or are you using it as a placeholder?

Comment: xxxx are the names of controls in the Default.aspx page. for example Button1, GridView1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1460833.aspx) as the solution for my problem. I can use this, to get my objects.

```
Label Label1 = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("Label1");
```

I don't know if it is the only solution. Maybe someone has better.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible causes of this problem.

One is that you have a [backup copy of this same file](http://dotnetfish.blogspot.com/2007/08/name-xxx-does-not-exst-in-current.html) somewhere in your project.

Another is that [two different ASPX files are using the same CS file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1006588.aspx) for code-behind.

A third is that you forgot to include System.Web or some other file you need.

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: Non of those. My page was working good, so the headers are ok. I didn't manipulate with the files. I just embraced my controls on the main page (Default.aspx) with LoginView control.

Comment: I had the same problem. I have checked and **two different ASPX files was using the same CS file**. Excluding the other file solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
This is a case copy project of web-application.
solution: Right click project in visualstudio choose "Convert to web application".
this is a good solution